# What kind of tree is this with pointed bumps on the trunk with small thorns on the ends?

Tags: identification, trees

I found a tree with tons of pointed bumps on the trunk with small thorns on the ends. I was wondering what type of tree it was. It was pretty tall and the bumps were at longest about 2 inches, it was alive too.[image]

Comment: Hi there, where was the picture taken?

Comment: it was taken in louisiana

Comment: Good question & illustration, and helpful comment; if could include an overall illustration, an illustration of the top, a close illustration of the leaves, overall height, trunk diameter, soil type, and if the tree is growing in a wet, medium or fairly dry location, could also be helpful. We encourage you to browse through the [Help] to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in [another answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/56070/32993) recently, this looks like [Zanthoxylum clava-herculis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanthoxylum_clava-herculis) to me based on the distinctive look and region (Louisiana) that you mentioned. It's also known as the Hercules' club, pepperwood, or southern prickly ash:

[image: tree photo]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely *Ceiba speciosa*, commonly known as Silk Floss tree, native to parts of South America - the trunk is green when the tree is young and is capable of photosynthesis when the leaves are not present. The trunk often has a bulbous base, though this feature is not always particularly pronounced. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiba_speciosa