# What is this spiky tree?

Tags: identification, trees

What is this spiky tree as seen in northern Mississippi?

[image]

Another one:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like [Zanthoxylum clava-herculis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanthoxylum_clava-herculis) to me based on the distinctive look and region that you mentioned. It's also known as the Hercules' club, pepperwood, or southern prickly ash:

[image: tree photo]

Here's the range distribution map:

[image: Range distribution map]

Answer (score 4):

It looks strikingly similar to these pictures in another [identification post.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55680/what-kind-of-tree-is-this-with-pointed-bumps-on-the-trunk-with-small-thorns-on-t)
Bamboo provided a bit more information about the plant called Ceiba speciosa. Perhaps the additional characteristics listed by Bamboo (bulbous base, not always pronounced) and the original poster of the similar/same identification question (thorns also present) are also true of the tree you found?

Bamboo stated it is commonly known as Silk Floss tree, native to parts of South America.

Comment: I'm new to the stack exchange community, is there a certain action that is taken when there seem to be duplicate posts?

Comment: Users with sufficient reputation can vote to close questions as duplicates of other questions. Users with less rep can still flag questions as duplicates for mods to look at. More info: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Without seeing the foliage, it would be hard to determine whether this tree is actually Ceiba or Zanthoxylum,the leaf arrangement is different between them.

Comment: The giant spikes in https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55680/what-kind-of-tree-is-this-with-pointed-bumps-on-the-trunk-with-small-thorns-on-t seem more similar to OP's tree than does the jncranton answer.